# Why multiple kernel does‘t improve the accuracy when some of kernel get weigths?

Tags: machine-learning, kernel, svm

Why  multiple kernel does‘t  improve the accuracy when some of kernel get weigths? it means multi-kernel  can't always improve the accuracy when we combine some kernel

Comment: I'm guessing you're trying to learn a linear combination of Kernels SVM classification (e.g., the simpleMKL formulation?).

From my 3 year old impression of MKL, *linear* Multiple Kernel Learning (MKL) methods often do not perform much better than the simplest combination of kernels (for example, the mean of all kernels).

Comment: yes,I use the simpeMKL.,if linear multi-kernel learning often do not perform much better than the single kerner, what's the meaning of mkl existence? how to use mkl improve accuracy ?

Comment: (1) Both theoretically and from an optimization stand point, linear combinations seem very appealing. The fact that a carefully tuned linear combination often fails to significantly improve upon a trivial combination is indeed disappointing. (2) I'm unsure about the state of the field these days (I didn't find MKL papers in last year's NIPS or ICML... maybe that's a sign..), but wouldn't be surprised to learn it has diminished.

Comment: thank  you  for your help

Comment: There's a good MKL survey from 2011. It compares different MKL formulations by conducting experiments against several (small-ish) datasets. No combination is consistently better, but the non-linear combinations show some promise (that is, they are more likely to beat the trivial "mean of all kernels"). See Figure 2-9 in the survey: http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume12/gonen11a/gonen11a.pdf

Comment: I have read the paper before,from figure 2,multi-kerner is better than single kerner on average,but not always !

Comment: I have read the paper before,from figure 2,multi-kerner is better than single kerner on average,but not always !aboute the paper ,I confuse that experiments uses the linear kerner to do mkl,but linear kerner is only a kerner     k(x,y)=<x,y>, so i can't understand it,if we do mkl,wo  shuld use many different kerners

Comment: I just noticed a a recent MKL paper that show some promise. Maybe you'd find it interesting -- NuC-MKL: A Convex Approach to Non Linear Multiple Kernel Learning

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of aspects of such question, I will list few of most common reasons:

- your data is to small to learn complex function without heavy overfitting
- your kernel weights assignment technique (optimization) is overfitting due to optimization nature and/or to flexible kernel ensemble definitions
- not optimizing something (like weights, kernels) is actually kind of regularization - if you start to fit this part, you increase variance of your method, thus you will need to compensate by some variance reduction technique (like additional regularizers)
- poor selection of kernels - too heavily correlated kernels, kernels with internal characteristic not well suited to the data might be a problem - weights assignment technique will struggle to remove redundant kernels

In general:

Each additional level of abstraction in the optimization process leads to non-linear growth in the problem complexity, thus in order to fit it correctly you need:

- more data
- better optimiztaion techniques
- better knowledge of underlying mathematical models

as compared to the use of simple model.

Comment: I use simpleMKL, what is better optimiztaion techniques?